# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable to System.Data.Entity.DbSet<>

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I receive the following error when I try to run my code. I haven't managed to solve it yet, please Help:

edit: Marked with * where it fails.
>

```
public IQueryable<Video> GetVideos([QueryString("id")] int? categorieId)
{
    var _db = new TeleviziuneAcademicaAspSilverlight.Models.VideoContext();
    IQueryable<Video> query = *_db.Videos;*
    if (categorieId.HasValue && categorieId > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(v => v.CategorieID == categorieId);
    }

    return query;
```

Comment: **Where** do you get that error?

Comment: I am not a compiler so I can be wrong but the code seems fine.

Comment: If you mouse over the Videos part of _db.Videos, what does it say the type is?

Comment: On mouse over @JasonP shows the following:                                                                       `Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Appname.Models.Video>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Appname.Video>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two classes called `Video`. If you need both, you'll need to project from one to the other before your return statement:

```
return query.Select(dbVideo => new Appname.Video()
    {
        Prop1 = dbVideo.Prop1,
        Prop2 = dbVideo.Prop2,
        // etc.
    });
```

Though you'll probably need to change the return type to an `IEnumerable<>` if you do that.

If you can just work with `Appname.Models.Video`, change `IQueryable<Video>` to `IQueryable<Appname.Models.Video>` in the method signature and the method body.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
IQueryable<Video> query =
```

to

```
IQueryable<Appname.Models.Video> query =
```

The reason for your error is that you have the type Video defined twice and because of using a short type name you accidentally reference not the one Video you should.

Also change it in the method's return value

```
public IQueryable<Appname.Models.Video> GetVideos( ... )
```

Comment: Change it in the method declaration's return value.
Should fix it.